# Global Component React Js

Tags: reactjs

I would like to have a global component Spinner.js to call in all components for show spinner.
This is my code with reference but doesn't work.

Root.js

```
export const spinner = React.createRef()

const Root = () => {

  return (

      {/* SPINNER */}    
        <SpinnerCustom ref={spinner} />
      {/* END SPINNER */}



      {/* NAV BAR */}
      <Navbar />
      {/* END NAV BAR */}

 

      {/* SWITCH */}
      <Switch>
        <Route component={Home} path="/" />
      </Switch>
      {/* END SWITCH */}

  )
}

export default Root;
```

Home.js

```
const Home = () => {

    function test(){
      spinner.show();
    }

    return (
      <>
      <button onClick={test}>TEST</button>
      </>
    );

}


export default Home;
```

I'm beginner with React.
Thanks all :)

Comment: What does the code for SpinnerCustom look like?

Comment: this is snippet of SpinnerCustom.js https://codepen.io/paolovox/pen/jOMYvWd

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the spinner when something changes, use a piece of state to listen for those changes. Here's a [full example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-http-259jn?file=/src/components/Spinner.js) on CodeSandbox.

The code:

1. Imports the `Spinner` component so it can be used inside `Home`.
2. Implements the [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to manage a piece of state called `visible`.
3. Attaches the `setVisible()` function to a button's click handler. Each time the button is pressed, the value of `visible` switches from `true` to `false` **or** from `false` to `true`.
4. [Conditionally renders](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) `<Spinner />` only when `visibility=true`.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Spinner from "./Spinner";

const Home = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        This is the Home component. The Spinner component has been imported, so
        I can use it below. The spinner will appear/disappear with each button press.</p>

      {visible ? <Spinner /> : null}

      <button onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>Toggle Spinner</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Exists a way to avoid import and reply Spinner in code every time? I would like recall it by using a global function startSpinner() stopSpinner()

Comment: I may not have understood your question. All components in React are reusable, and therefore global. If you want to create reusable functions, that is also possible. To create reusable helper functions just create a file (like `helpers.js`) and save your functions there. Note, the helper functions still need to be imported/exported with [Node import statements](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_statements).